# how to copy and paste multiple columns with awk

Tags: bash, awk, multiple-columns

I'm trying to copy and paste the sixth column from a bunch of files into a single file having each column pasted in separate columns (and not one after each other in just one column.)

I tried this code but it works only partially because it only copied and pasted 50 rows of each column instead of the total number which is 114

```
 awk 'FNR==1{f++}{a[f,FNR]=$6}END{for(x=1;x<=FNR;x++){for(y=1;y<ARGC;y++)printf("%s ",a[y,x]);print ""}}' *.label > fname.txt
```

Comment: awk 'FNR==1{f++}{a[f,FNR]=$6}END{for(x=1;x<=FNR;x++){for(y=1;y<ARGC;y++)printf("%s ",a[y,x]);print ""}}' *.label > fname.txt

Comment: Use the [edit] button to update your question, don't add code or anything else in comments under it. Also, please format your code by indenting it 4 spaces (or use the editors `{}` button) and provide concise, testable sample input and expected output (use 4 or 5 columns in your example input, output, and code, not 115).

Comment: Wow, this code is illegible, but I'm impressed: when I run it, it does exactly what you describe, getting all the rows in the test files I created. You might need to specify your version of awk and the platform you run on, in case that matters.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed, it stops as soon as the last file hits its last line. Do your files have a different number of lines? So it looks to me like you need `max{FNR from each file}` instead of `FNR`, which I now gather is the last line number of the last file read.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `FNR` in the `END` clause is the number of lines in the last file. If that file is shorter than other files then only that number of rows will be printed. Saving the largest file length as you go then using that in the `for` loop will make your code work as expected.

```
  awk 'FNR==1{f++}{a[f,FNR]=$6; if (FNR > longest) {longest = FNR} }END{for(x=1; x <= longest ;x++){for(y=1;y<ARGC;y++)printf("%s ",a[y,x]);print ""}}' *.label > fname.txt
```